# Github.com merge company user heatmap with personal heatmap

Tags: git, github

I have a company github account on github.com, and using personal access token to make commits.

I also have a personal github.com account with my personal email. I want to have my commits heat map to show on my personal github.com account.

I tried setting user.email on my git config to my personal email, and have company emails personal access token as password, but still it is not showing on my personal github.com accounts heat map.  When I go to the commit history on company github, I can see my personal email id as commit email.

How can I show private commits on company email account on my personal github.com heat map ?

Answer (score 0):

> have company emails personal access token as password,

That would allow you to push to company repositories.

Check if those commits follows the [official criteria](https://docs.github.com/en/account-and-profile/setting-up-and-managing-your-github-profile/managing-contribution-settings-on-your-profile/why-are-my-contributions-not-showing-up-on-my-profile#contributions-that-are-counted):

> Commits will appear on your contributions graph if they meet all of the following conditions:
>
> - The email address used for the commits is associated with your account on GitHub.com.
> - The commits were made in a standalone repository, not a fork.
> - The commits were made:
>
>   - In the repository's default branch
>   - In the `gh-pages` branch (for repositories with project sites)

> In addition, at least one of the following must be true:
>
> - You are a collaborator on the repository or are a member of the organization that owns the repository.
> - You have forked the repository.
> - You have opened a pull request or issue in the repository.
> - You have starred the repository.

In your case, make sure your own account (the one with your personal email) is part of the company's organization.